# Moving dynamic rigidbody from point A to point B in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I need to move a dynamic rigidbody from point A to point B. I know how to do so with a kinematic rigidbody, below the code:

```
[SerializeField] Transform destination;
[SerializeField] float moveTime = 0.1f;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private float inverseMoveTime;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    inverseMoveTime = 1f / moveTime;
    Move(destination.position.x, destination.position.y);
}

public void Move(float xDir, float yDir)
{
    Vector2 start = rb.velocity;
    Vector2 end = start + new Vector2(xDir, yDir);
    StartCoroutine(SmoothMovement(end));
}

public IEnumerator SmoothMovement(Vector3 end)
{
    float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

    while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon) // While that distance is greater than a very small amount (Epsilon, almost zero):
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime); // Find a new position proportionally closer to the end, based on the moveTime

        rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y));

        sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude; // Recalculate the remaining distance after moving.

        yield return null; // Return and loop until sqrRemainingDistance is close enough to zero to end the function
    }

    rb.MovePosition(end);
}
```

The problem is that using the function rigidbody.MovePosition() doesn't work well with dynamic rigidbodies, as Unity's docs and my experiments prove.

I've then tried with the following code, but it leads to weird results: the toon moves in the opposite direction of its destination! And the acceleration keeps increasing, the latter seeming the only point I think I can solve pretty easily.

```
    [SerializeField] Transform destination;
    [SerializeField] float moveTime;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float inverseMoveTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        inverseMoveTime = 1f / moveTime;
        Move(destination.position.x, destination.position.y);
    }

    public void Move(float xDir, float yDir)
    {
        Vector2 startVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector2 end = startVelocity + new Vector2(xDir, yDir);
        StartCoroutine(SmoothMovement(end));
    }

    public IEnumerator SmoothMovement(Vector3 end)
    {
        float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

        while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon) // While that distance is greater than a very small amount (Epsilon, almost zero):
        {
            Vector2 newPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(rb.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime); // Find a new position proportionally closer to the end, based on the moveTime

            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y), ForceMode2D.Force);

            sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude; // Recalculate the remaining distance after moving.

            yield return null; // Return and loop until sqrRemainingDistance is close enough to zero to end the function
        }

        rb.MovePosition(end);
    }
```

It's very similar to the first one, changing the way the character moves within the coroutine.

Basically my problem now is: how can I calculate the Vector2 to use withing the function AddForce(Vector2, ForceMode2D.Force) in the coroutine, so that it simply leads my character towards the destination and then the character stops when the destination is reached? Moreover, it should reach the destination at a constant speed, instead of keeping accelerating (but as I was saying above, I think I can solve this easily).

If you know any other way to move a 2D object with a dynamic rigidbody from point A to point B which is effective, of course, it's fine anyways: the coroutine seemed to me a good way but not mandatory. The only requirement is that it doesn't have to be a "tricky" way like transform.position or translate or any other function which ignores the phyisics.

Thanks again for the patience and for the next answer :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you could simply **make** your Rigidbody a `kinematic` for the time the routine is running. **But** in general you should make sure that your code is executed in `FixedUpdate` not every frame

```
public IEnumerator SmoothMovement(Vector2 end)
{   
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

    rb.isKinematic = true;

    // If you really need a precision down to epsilon
    //while (!Mathf.Approximately(Vector2.Distance(rb.position, end), 0f))
    // otherwise for most use cases in physics the default precision of 
    // 0.00001f should actually be enough
    while(rb.position != end)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }

    rb.position = end;
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

---

What I don't understand though is why you pass in a **position** and treat it as it would be a **direction** added to the current **velocity** ...

If your goal is moving towards a certain position then rather simply do

```
StartCoroutine (SmoothMovement(destination.position));
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply! Yes you're right, I had to wait for FixedUpdate, definitely; and the switch to the kinematic rigidbody is absolutely a good idea. For the position question, I pass it treating it as a proper "vector", maybe I'm wrong but since it's a vector I should be able to pass it as a parameter for the speed, but I'm absolutely new to vectors math so I may be wrong. I'll try out your solution and report the results, thanks!

Comment: I got now what you meant with just passing the destination.position, and it actually works. In the tutorial I followed (on Unity Learn, the 2D roguelike project) it was one of the passages that I didn't get clearly and in fact we can just do as you suggest, without problems.
My main concern anyways is: given a certain destination, how can I calculate how much acceleration (and drag?) I need to apply to the rigidbody in order to make it smoothly move to the destination and stops there? I've not found a satisfying solution yet to this issue :(